# 'serviceHostingEnvironment' and 'endpointBehaviors' in code write

Tags: c#, wcf

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>



<endpointBehaviors>
   <behavior name="WebBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

How to write code way, not in the configuration file to write.

Answer (score 0):

You can define binding from code of course,

You can try like this at the startup

```
 ServiceEndpoint se = new ServiceEndpoint(new ContractDescription("IService1"), new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("basic"));  
            se.Behaviors.Add(new MyEndpointBehavior());  
            config.AddServiceEndpoint(se);  

            config.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });  
            config.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDebugBehavior { IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true });
```

At the wcf side you can alter your configuration like this

```
public class Service1 : IService1   
{   
    public void DoWork();   
    public static void Configure(ServiceConfiguration config)   
    {   
          config.LoadFromConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = @"c:\sharedConfig\MyConfig.config" }, ConfigurationUserLevel.None));   
    }   
}
```